# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates not setting location

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get real-time location updates using the `GoogleAPIClient`. While `GoogleAPIClient` is connected but the location object is null and it complains that `location.getProvider()` is null. Can someone please help?

This is my code :

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient " + myGoogleApiClient.isConnected());

    myCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(myGoogleApiClient);
    // Debug - At this point myCurrentLocation  is NULL
        if (myCurrentLocation == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "myCurrentLocation is : " + myCurrentLocation);
            // Debug - myCurrentLocation  is STILL NULL
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    myGoogleApiClient, myLocationRequest, this);
            // Debug - app crashes with stack trace below at this point
            Log.i(TAG, "Doesnt't reach here : " + myCurrentLocation);
        }

        myLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUILayout();

}

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    myGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    Log.i(TAG, "myGoogleApiClient is :" + myGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    myLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    myLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    myLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    myLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

The main problem after debugging I found was with:

```
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    myGoogleApiClient, myLocationRequest, this);
```

This is not setting myCurrentLocation. It's always NULL. And in the ADB logcat says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.location.Location.getProvider()' on a null object reference
        at com.adrenalin.myfirstapp.MyActivity.onConnected(MyActivity.java:130)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.f(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.gJ(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.d(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.f(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.jm.dU(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.b(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are implementing

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    myGoogleApiClient, myLocationRequest, this);
```

you need to override the callback for `onLocationChanged` so that it knows what to do with the location as it updates.

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    myCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()` snippet ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using a fragment class, is there any workaround for using *this* on LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()?

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        displayLocation();
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED     )
        {
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLastLocation,this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following method if you are getting Null localion

```
if (myCurrentLocation == null) { 
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
} else {
    //your location code here...
}
```

And override following method for retrying for location

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   //your location code here...
}
```